# How to get access to filesystem with "kubectl debug" (ephemeral containers)?

Tags: kubernetes

If I do

```
POD=$($KUBECTL get pod -lsvc=app,env=production -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl debug -it --image=mpen/tinker "$POD" -- zsh -i
```

I can get into a shell running inside my pod, but I want access to the filesystem for a container I've called "php". I think this should be at `/proc/1/root/app` but that directory doesn't exist. For reference, my Dockerfile has:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```

So all the files should be in the root `/app` directory.

If I add `--target=php` then I get permission denied:

```
❯ cd /proc/1/root
cd: permission denied: /proc/1/root
```

How do I get access to the files?

Comment: The `--target` option is the right approach. There are two other constraints: the containers have to run as the same user, and the underlying container runtime has to support the option.

Answer (score 16):

The debug container has always its own filesystem, but - if the container runtime supports it - you should be able to use `--target` and access it via `/proc/$PID/root` just fine. One just needs to act as the exact same user (both `$UID` and `$GID` must match).

### Example

First, prepare a container to be debugged:

```bash
kubectl run tested-pod --rm -it --image=busybox:latest --restart=Never \
  --overrides='
    {"spec": {
      "containers": [
        {
          "name":"tested-pod",
          "image":"busybox:latest",
          "stdin":true,
          "tty":true,
          "securityContext": {
            "runAsUser":1234,
            "runAsGroup":4321
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }' \
  -- sh
```

This creates a new pod `tested-pod` where the container runs with `UID=1234` and `GID=4321`, and gives you an interactive shell. Write something to the container's filesystem, so you can see it later:

```bash
touch /tmp/tested-pod-file
ls /tmp
# tested-pod-file
```

Next, open a new terminal and use the ephemeral container `debug`:

```bash
kubectl debug tested-pod -it --image=busybox:latest --target=tested-pod -- sh
```

At this moment, the debugging user is `root`, which can't access the FS, but we can already see the container's process:

```bash
id
# uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),10(wheel)
ls /proc/1/root
# ls: /proc/1/root: Permission denied
ps -o 'pid,user,group,comm'
# PID   USER     GROUP    COMMAND
#     1 1234     4321     sh
#     9 root     root     sh
#    25 root     root     ps
```

Now you gotta create a local group and user (name doesn't matter) and use it:

```bash
addgroup -g 4321 karel
adduser -HD -u 1234 -G karel karel
su karel
```

In the resulting shell you should be able to access the filesystem, even for writing (at least it works in my case):

```bash
ls /proc/1/root/tmp/
# tested-pod-file
touch /proc/1/root/tmp/debugger-file
ls /proc/1/root/tmp/
# debugger-file    tested-pod-file
```

You can verify this worked from the original container's shell:

```bash
ls /tmp
debugger-file    tested-pod-file
```

Comment: This answer set me on the right track. Thanks you! The switches for adduser and addgroup weren't recognized in my Ubuntu (-g was ambiguous) debug container and had to use 
addgroup -gid 472 karel and adduser -u 472 -gid 0 tom 
(my use case for Grafana required the use to be in the root group as well)

Answer (score 4):

Reading through [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/), using `kubectl debug` won't give you access to the filesystem in another container.

The simplest option may be to use `kubectl exec` to start a shell inside an existing container. There are some cases in which this isn't an option (for example, some containers contain only a single binary, and won't have a shell or other common utilities avaiable), but a php container will typically have a complete filesystem.

In this case, you can simply:

```
kubectl exec -it $POD -- sh
```

You can replace `sh` by `bash` or `zsh` depending on what shells are available in the existing image.

---

The linked documentation provides several other debugging options, but all involve working on *copies of* the pod.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out how to avoid adding a shell to all my containers. Even with the copy feature, I could only find a /secrets volume I mounted, not the rest of my files.

Comment: The best option may be start a debug shell on the underlying node; then you use the `container inspect` command provided by your container runtime and navigate directly to the container filesystem.

Comment: The `/proc/1/root` **can be made accessible**. The preconditions are not satisfied in the snippet in the question, but it can be done and is the preferred approach.

Comment: `/proc/1/root` is inaccessible when the main container is in a crash loop.

Comment: You can modify the pod/deployment manifest to run a no-op command (`sleep inf`), and then it won't crash. Now you can exec into the container, attempt to run the normal start command interactively, etc.